# RabbitMQ convenience wrappers for .NET

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

I've looked at both MassTransit and EasyNetQ.  Both provide useful functionality to supplement the base RabbitMQ client, like the ability to define a subscriber as a delegate/event listener, and infrastructure to handle failure cases.

My issue is, both seem to also impose an opinion about message types and routing.  Is there anything out there that gives you the conveniences without the baggage of type-based routing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Daishi.AMQP](https://github.com/daishisystems/Daishi.AMQP) wraps the boilerplate aspects of RabbitMQ interfacing, while allowing the flexibility to define your own message-structure, etc. [Here](http://insidethecpu.com/2015/07/17/microservices-in-c-part-1-building-and-testing/) is a tutorial.